# Twilio API request limit / throttle?

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I have a c# service which runs through a list of clients , for each client a number search is performed and if successful a number purchased.

The service works successfully however I have noticed that it seems to stop randomly when calling the Twilio API.

Is there any form of throttling or request limiting per account?

For our initial import of clients we have 1000 odd records and it seems to stop about 350 records in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Twilio evangelist here.

There isn't any request throttling for making [requests to the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers).  Are you making each request sequentially or are you doing it in parallel.

Remember that by default Windows limits the number of outbound HTTP connections to 2, so you might be asking Windows to make a bunch of requests that its dropping onto the floor.  You can change that by setting the [DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

Another suggestion for debugging is to break out fiddler and see if there are 1000 outbound requests being made, where some % are not receiving a response, or if for some reason requests are not even being made.

Hope that helps.